# Cypress interception is not waiting

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress 6.0.0 new way of interception.
[Waiting on a request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Waiting-on-a-request)

I need to wait for the "templatecontract" response in order to click the #template-button-next because otherwise is disabled. But is trying to click it before getting the response from the API. The documentation seems pretty straight forward.

Am I wrong here?

I have also tried just like:

```
cy.wait('@templatecontract')
cy.get('#template-button-next').click()
```

```
it("Test", function() {
    cy.intercept(Cypress.env("baseUrl")+`/api/v1/contract-type/templatecontract`).as('templatecontract')
    cy.login(Cypress.env('testUserInviteEmail'), Cypress.env('testUserInvitePassword')).then((token) => {

        cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl')+"/templates", {headers: {
            Authorization: token,
          },
        });
        cy.get('a[href="/create-template"]').click();
        cy.get('.template-usecasetitle').contains('UBO-Formular')
        cy.get('button[cy-data="Formular"]').click();
        cy.get('#title').type("Title for testing");
        cy.get('#usecasetitle').type("Usecasetitle for testing")
        cy.get('#description').type("Description just for testing")
        cy.wait('@templatecontract').then(interceptions => {
            cy.get('#template-button-next').click()
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: did you get a solution to this problem. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why but just setting the method type (POST in this case) have solved the problem.

```
cy.intercept('POST', Cypress.env("baseUrl")+`/api/v1/contract-type/templatecontract`).as('templatecontract')
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and the issue was that the first request my application sent was an OPTIONS request.

If you do not include the method as the first argument, all methods (including OPTIONS) are now matched. This can be puzzling as your `.wait` will be satisfied by the OPTIONS request, not by your second POST request.

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Comparison-to-cy-route
Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Matching-URL

Answer (score 1):

If you spy a route at the top of your test, as you do here, `cy.wait()` will return immediately if there have already been responses to that route by the time it's called.

As an example, say you notice this in your network tab:

```
GET some-route: 200
GET some-route: 200
GET some-route: 200
GET some-route: 200
POST something-unique: 200
GET some-route: 500
```

^ some-route is 500ing at some clearly-identifiable point. Should be easy to catch in a test, right? Well:

```
it('Should fail on this 500, but doesn't???', () => {
  // start spying our indicator; seems good:
  cy.intercept('GET', 'something-unique').as('indicator')
  // but if we start spying the route here:
  cy.intercept('POST', 'some-route').as('route')

  // then hit some-route a bunch of times & return:
  foo()

  // then expect to catch the failure after something-unique fires:
  cy.wait('@indicator').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200).then( () => {
  // then expect the test to fail on the 500:
  cy.wait('@route').its('response.statusCode).should('not.eq', 500) 
  // ...this won't work! this test will pass because cy.wait() will
  // succeed and return the *first* GET some-route: 200 !
})
```

I personally find this to be pretty counter-intuitive - it feels reasonable that a wait() on a spied route would always actually wait for the next request! - but that's apparently not how it works.

One way around this is to not start spying until you're actually ready:

```
it('Fails on a 500', () => {
  cy.intercept('GET', 'something-unique').as('indicator')
  foo()

  cy.wait('@indicator').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200).then( () => {
  // don't start spying until ready:
  cy.intercept('POST', 'some-route').as('route')
  cy.wait('@route').its('response.statusCode).should('not.eq', 500) 
  // and the test fails correctly; response.statusCode 500 should not equal 500
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I am getting different results for

```
cy.intercept("POST", "https://backend.rocketgraph.app/api/signup").as("doSignup")
```

and

```
cy.intercept("POST", `${BACKEND_URL}/signup`).as("doSignup")
```

Not sure what is the issue. Also have to set `POST` as one of the users have mentioned

The first one is actually intercepted. Weird but happened.